# There was an error creating an object using the Image.file constructor

Tags: flutter, io

I was trying to create a widget with an image using Image.file (), but an error occurred while I was trying

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(StateApp());
}

class StateApp extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return Application();
  }
}

class Application extends State<StateApp> {
  Widget build(BuildContext con) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: Image.file(File("/home/suchin/1.png")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error log:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following UnsupportedError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unsupported operation: _Namespace

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

...

Path: /home/user/1.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

From where are you getting the path? that doesn't look like a mobile path

Try this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) to pick images, and then you can display with the result